# Smooth map on manifolds from a given closed subset to a given point

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I recently learned that if $M$ and $N$ are both manifolds, then for a smooth map $F:M\to N$, the preimage $F^{-1}(q)$ of a point $q\in N$ is always a closed subset of $M$. How about the other direction? If we are given a closed subset $S\subset M$ and a point $q\in N$, can we define a smooth map $F:M\to N$ such that $S=F^{-1}(q)$ explicitly? Thank you!

Comment: I'd try to use partition of unit to reduce to the case of a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where this is known to be true (see here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set). To get from $N=\mathbb{R}$ to general $N$ you need that the manifold has at least dimension $1$. If $N$ is zero-dimensional, then your statement is obviously wrong (as any continuous function into $N$ would be constant if $M$ is connected).

Comment: I would say maybe if you have a compact manifold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, if $\dim N > 0$ (as @SeverinSchraven points out in the comments) via the following result from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:

> **Theorem 2.29 (Level Sets of Smooth Functions).** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. If $K$ is any closed subset of $M$, there is a smooth nonnegative function $f\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = K$.

Taking such an $f$ and composing it with a smooth map $i\colon \mathbb{R} \to N$ such that $i^{-1}(q) = \{0\}$ then yields the result.

Comment: Nice answer. Though it is probably not wise to call $i$ an embedding (in general there might not exist an embedding from $\mathbb{R}$ into $N$, e.g. if $N$ is compact). However, we can pick any smooth mapping $i:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow N$ such that $i^{-1}(\{q\})=\{0\}$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: If $N$ is not $0$-dimensional, there always exist smooth embeddings from $\mathbb R$ into $N$. Just choose a smooth coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$, so $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism from $U\subseteq N$ to an open set $\widehat U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and consider the restriction of $\phi^{-1}$ to the intersection of $\widehat U$ with a straight line. Each connected component of that set is diffeomorphic to an open interval in $\mathbb R$, which in turn is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @JackLee Sigh, sometimes I really wonder what I am thinking while typing. Thanks for the correction.